# How to fetch list of repositories in github as part of shell script?

Tags: git, shell, github

Using shell script, I want to list down the git repositories (part of github) and build only the project based on the chosen repository by the user (Gradle is used as build tool)

```
Example:
[1] Repository_1
[2] Repository_2
[3] Repository_3
```

If the user chooses 2, then the project part of Repository_2 should be build

Answer (score 2):

To list down all the GitHub repositories you can curl the GitHub API:

```
USER=GITHUBUSERMANE; curl -s "https://api.github.com/users/$USER/repos" | grep -o 'git@[^"]*'
```

The API will also provide you with the URL for clone the API. On selected repo, you can trigger the script to clone the repo from them and run the build commands.

Comment: Please advise how to access the same if its a enterprise github with URL like https://github.org.com

Comment: You can only get the repository list for a user, as an organization might have certain numbers of the repository but the developer might not have the access to all, this API is user based. While you can get the private repos for a user as well by passing the access token for that user

Comment: You can refer to https://developer.github.com/v3/ for more info on Github's API.
The section relevant to your use case would be Organization and users. @user6835509